# Is It posible to attach block files stored in Azure Storage to an email via AMPScript or JS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, attachment, azure

In this link there is info about how to attach a file to an email:

[**Email Attachments**](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_attachments/)

Nevertheless, I am struggling to find a solution to my problem. The files I need to attach are stored in Azure Storage in block format, and I can't find a way to access them dynamically via AMPScript.

Anyone faced this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on the [**AttachFile()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/attachfile2/) AMPScript function says you can only attach files of these types:

- Microsoft Word documents (.doc, .docx)
- Microsoft Excel documents (.xls, .xlsx)
- Microsoft Powerpoint documents (.ppt, .pptx)
- Adobe PDF documents (.pdf)
- ZIP archive files (.zip)
- Compressed archive files (.rar)
- PNG images (.png)
- GIF images (.gif)
- JPEG images (.jpg, .jpeg)
- TIFF images (.tif, .tiff)
- Video files (.mp4)
- ICS file (.ics)

If your file is accessible on your Azure Storage via http/https and is one of these formats, you should be able to attach it.

If it's not accessible, then you'll need to make it accessible in one of these places:

- another website (http/https)
- SFMC FTP
- SFMC Portfolio
- SFMC Content Builder